# Amazon Simple Workflow - Given workflowID List all executions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Workflow when started again, with the same workflowID, but it gets a different runID. Is there a way to retrieve such executions (containing different runID) of a given workflow ID?

I explored `ListClosedWorkflowExecutionsRequest` API, but it just lists all the workflow executions, not for a particular workflowID.

The problem I am trying to solve is: There were many workflows that failed for some reason. In restarting the process, I didn't include a correct time filter and few of them were restarted while a few got skipped. So I am trying to list all failed workflow IDs using `ListClosedWorkflowExecutionsRequest`. For each workflowID, fetch all executions and if latest of them is successful, skip it else restart.

I am little new to SWF, so is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to filter by workflowId as described in 
[How do you get the state of a WorkflowExecution if all you have is a workflowId in Amazon SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775975/how-do-you-get-the-state-of-a-workflowexecution-if-all-you-have-is-a-workflowid/17783323).

The answer is on line [7] and [9] in the example, the `executions()` method call. For your use case though, since all you want are closed executions, you'll just alter the method call to include `closed=True`. So, in order to get all closed executions in the 24hours (the default):

```
In [7]: domain.executions(closed=True)
```

And for closed executions filtered by workflow id:

```
In [9]: domain.executions(workflow_id='my_wf_id', closed=True)
```

If you're not using `boto.swf` but an alternative library instead, refer to the API docs for what are the necessary parameters to pass to the [ListClosedWorkflowExecutions API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ListClosedWorkflowExecutions.html).

Comment: Didn't know about ExecutionFilter which accepts workflowId, in  ListClosedWorkflowExecutions API before. Thanks